# I got an empty array in sub document array saving using mongoose ( MEAN stack)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I'm having a problem when tried to save schema with sub document arrays. Sub documents are saved as blanks. Please help me.

Thank you

> schema.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var contactSchema = new Schema({
    first_name:String,
    last_name:String,
    phone:String,   
    meta:[{
        clg_name: String,
        class_name:String,
        roll_number: String
    }]
});
```

var contact=mongoose.model('contact',contactSchema);
module.exports=contact;

> route
>
> const express= require('express'); const router= express.Router();
>   const Contact= require('../models/contacts');
>
> //get  contact router.get('/contacts',(req,res,next)=>{
>       Contact.find(function(err,contacts){
>           if (err) throw err;
>           res.json(contacts);
>       })
>       });
>       //add contact(form1)
>       router.post('/contact',(req,res,next)=>{
>           let newContact=new Contact({
>               first_name:req.body.first_name,
>               last_name:req.body.last_name,
>               phone:req.body.phone,
>               clg_name:req.body.clg_name,
>               class_name:req.body.class_name,
>               roll_number:req.body.roll_number
>
> ```
>     });
>
>     newContact.save((err,Contact)=>
>     {
>         if(err) 
>         {
>
>             res.json({msg:"contact does not save"});
>         }
>             else{
>                 console.log(Contact);
>                 res.json({msg:"contact is saved"});
>             }
>     });
>
> });
> ```
>
> //detete contact router.delete('/contact/:id',(req,res,next)=>{
>       Contact.remove({_id:req.params.id} ,function(err,result){
>           if(err)
>           { res.json(err);
>           }
>           else{ res.json(result);
>           }
>       }); });
>
> module.exports=router;
>
> mongodb database

```
{ 
    >         "_id" : ObjectId("5b3c6e4ea380651ebcf762ea"), 
    >         "first_name" : "ang", 
    >         "last_name" : "raw", 
    >         "phone" : "123456", 
    >         "meta" : [
    >     
    >         ], 
    >         "__v" : NumberInt(0)
    >     }
```

[database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8Yvj.png)///[form input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glHtB.png)

Comment: Please do not post your source code as image. Write the code in your question and indent it with 4 spaces.

Comment: please click 2 for getting source code..

Comment: No. That is an image of the source code. Paste the _text_ of the source code and indent it with 4 spaces.

Comment: i edited this question ...now you check.

Comment: You just posted the schema. We need also: how you use it, what the expected result is, what the actual result is, the input data. Please, add that.

Comment: Could you please stop posting code as external images? The result can be posted as text, too (with indentation).

Comment: i want a sub document in meta ..but i did not get i got ///...meta:[]

Comment: { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b1fcda3ded07828e3e03252"), 
    "first_name" : "vivek ", 
    "last_name" : "tiwari", 
    "phone" : "899899", 
    "meta" : [ ]
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}

Comment: This belongs in the __question__, _instead_ of the image...

Comment: Which output did you expect? What is in req?

Comment: i got//first_name" : "shiv", 
    "last_name" : "NARAYAN", 
    "phone" : "12346", 
    "meta" : [

    ], 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}

Comment: Now guess where that belongs...

Comment: i did not  make sub document ...i got empty array or  ,i did not get the value in my sub document

Comment: Yes. Edit your question accordingly. It is hard to answer a question, if you have to pick all information out of comments.

Comment: now you check..

Comment: You just broke the formatting of the code. Unreadable code makes your question hard to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is problem in req.body and also don't print req.body.createdObject because body doesnot contain it without assigning. 

Try to create a new variable and put values of body in that then save with new Contact(newVariable).